# fixed header to container not working when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to javascript so please bear with me. I had a container with slides in it and has a header with a red background color and I added some javascript and CSS to make the header stick to the top when I scroll down but the function is not sticking the header when I scroll down. I can't figure out where I went wrong. My current code is attached below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```css
.Con1 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 70%;
}

.slideWrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  width: 95%;
}

.ConHeader {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.Scroll {
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  right: 1%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="swiper-container Con1">
    <div class="ConHeader" id="ConHeader"></div>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper slideWrap">
      <div class="swiper-slide Slide1">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide Slide2">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide Slide3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar Scroll"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.Con1', {
      direction: 'vertical',
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 10,
      scrollbar: {
        el: '.Scroll',
        hide: true,
      },
      mousewheel: {
        invert: false,
        forceToAxis: true,
      },
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var sticky = $('.ConHeader'),
        scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (scroll >= 100) sticky.addClass('fixed');
      else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```